# flag tuples with unique values

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I want to flag for uniqueness of one of the values. For example:

```
tupes = [(a,1),(a,2),(b,2),(c,3)]

output =[(a,1,unique),(a,2,repeat),(b,2,repeat),(c,3,unique)]
```

I've tried the below based on other examples, but it only preserves the first pairing of Y, rather than keeping unique values:

```
seen = set()
keep = []
for x, y in tupes:
    if y in seen:
        pass
    else:
        seen.add(y)
        keep.append((x, y))
```

I have a working program using flipped dictionaries, but it re-structures the data over and over again and is generally inefficient. Functioning, but ugly.

What is a better way to go about this?

Comment: Flipped dictionaries is exactly how I'd do this.  Why is that inefficient or ugly? 
 Unless the data is sorted, you're going to have to consume the entire list before yielding any elements anyway.

Comment: @wim It was duplicating a lot of work and if I start from a list of tuples, I won't need to flip back and forth to process everything. Passing the final arguments ended up being done through a couple lists and a dictionary, when all that was really needed was a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` and then a list comprehension to run over elements marking them as `'unique'` or `'repeat'`:

```
from collections import Counter

tupes = [('a',1),('a',2),('b',2),('c',3)]

c = Counter(x[1] for x in tupes)
output = [x + ('unique',) if c[x[1]] == 1 else x + ('repeat',) for x in tupes]

# [('a', 1, 'unique'), ('a', 2, 'repeat'), ('b', 2, 'repeat'), ('c', 3, 'unique')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
from collections import Counter
tupes = [('a',1),('a',2),('b',2),('c',3)]
counts = Counter(x[1] for x in tupes)
counts_dict = dict(counts)
f = [(x,y,"unique" if counts_dict.get(y)==1 else "repeat")  for x,y in tupes]
```

output

```
[('a', 1, 'unique'),('a', 2, 'repeat'), ('b', 2, 'repeat'),('c', 3, 'unique')]
```